# Token transfer not dropped no event on MetaMask

Tags: tokens, erc-20, golang

I am using the following contract

[Fixed Contract Example](https://gist.github.com/jonchurch/c71de291b3ffa49ae17e416393f87135)

And using this example to transfer token

[Transfer token example](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book/blob/master/code/transfer_tokens.go)

Everything goes fine, i see no error what so ever except MetaMask doesn't show any event at all

On geth i see the transaction was submitted fine:

```
Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x70fea648cd4d5b5cce676c31c457ac98e3d5b4a9c302c8aaab3d1ba62f0878fe recipient=0x64ff6c91666Ab1C2f1b19dAE13E9B1733bD3aF5D
```

I see that the code executed fine with the same tx hash:

```
  Method ID: 0xa9059cbb
To address: 0x000000000000000000000000da27b58c82f5e04ed634cf54eb93ba0e50e6beb4
Token amount: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003635c9adc5dea00000
Gas limit: 23256
Tokens sent at TX: 0x70fea648cd4d5b5cce676c31c457ac98e3d5b4a9c302c8aaab3d1ba62f0878fe
```

How do i debug to understand what went wrong ? Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Thee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it seems the the transaction is waiting to be approved. just need to extend my code to trigger the event.

Thanks,
Thee

Answer (score 0):

Use etherscan to check what happened to your ERC-20 tokens.

Comment: Working locally, have an explorer, found the issue with the approval.